# R - Geom_Col com divisão por ano

Tags: r, ggplot2

Caros,

Tenho a seguinte base de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero montar um gráfico como o abaixo usando o ggplot:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer isso com o seguinte código, mas não estou conseguindo um bom resultado.

> ggplot(Database, aes(x = Grupo, y = Dados)) +
>     geom_col(aes(fill = Ano))

O resultado está abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem uma ideia do que pode ser?
Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Tente `geom_col(aes(fill = Ano), position = "dodge")`. Ou talvez `geom_col(aes(fill = Ano), position = position_dodge())`. E `fill = factor(Ano)` para ter uma escala discreta, assim é contínua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segue uma solução:

```
library(dplyr) # Para manipulação dos dados
library(ggplot2) # Para fazer gráficos
# Criando seus dados:
dados <- data_frame(Grupo = rep(c("Asia", "Europe", "Northern American", "Africa", "LAC", "Oceania"), each = 2),
                    Dados = c(49.2, 79.6, 56.3, 77.9, 40.4, 57.7, 14.8, 24.7, 6.6, 9.5, 5.4, 8.4),
                    Ano = rep(c("2000", "2017"), times = 6))

# Converter ano para fator:
# Obs.: um dos seus problemas.
dados <- 
  dados %>% 
  mutate(Ano = factor(x = Ano,
                      levels = c("2000", "2017"))) # ordem em que os anos aparecem na legenda (ggplot controla assim) 

dados %>% 
  ggplot(aes( x = Grupo, y = Dados, fill = Ano)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Dados, hjust = ifelse(Ano == "2000", 1.25, -.25)), vjust = -.5) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Se quiser mudar a ordem do Grupo, faça a mesma coisa que fiz para o ano. Você pode usar o comando `coord_flip()` para rotacionar o gráfico.